# PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver Cannot search for matching files underneath URL because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system

Tags: spring, websphere, osgi, websphere-liberty

I am facing the error from subject and I have no idea where I can give a try. The most interesting thing is that the application is running perfectly. I searched in the internet and I found some similar topics from some OSGI users. Although I am not interested in using OSGI and I believe Spring 4 don't have default support or dependency on OSGI, I can see this word in the log below related to IBM namespace. I am using Websphere Liberty Profile v8.5, Spring 4, JDK 6 and maven. I found the link below explaining about PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver to be used to manage classPath but I am not using this object, at least I am not using it explicitly.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html

```
product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.3 (wlp-1.0.6.cl50320140731-0257)
wlp.install.dir = C:/IBMliberty/
java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre
java.version = 1.6.0_45
java.runtime = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.6.0_45-b06)
os = Windows 7 (6.1; amd64) (en_US)
********************************************************************************
[11/26/14 14:20:44:301 CST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.TraceSpecification               I TRAS0018I: The trace state has been changed. The new trace state is *=info.
[11/26/14 14:20:44:326 CST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[11/26/14 14:20:49:151 CST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           I CWWKE0002I: The kernel started after 5.375 seconds
[11/26/14 14:20:49:270 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0007I: Feature update started.
[11/26/14 14:20:56:450 CST] 00000011 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.monitor.DropinMonitor        A CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[11/26/14 14:20:57:386 CST] 0000001c com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.TCPChannel                    I CWWKO0219I: TCP Channel defaultHttpEndpoint has been started and is now listening for requests on host 127.0.0.1  (IPv4: 127.0.0.1) port 8080.
[11/26/14 14:21:01:192 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            I CWWKF0008I: Feature update completed in 12.117 seconds.
[11/26/14 14:21:01:193 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.FeatureManager            A CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[11/26/14 14:24:05:977 CST] 00000016 com.ibm.ws.config.xml.internal.ConfigRefresher               A CWWKG0016I: Starting server configuration update.
[11/26/14 14:24:08:618 CST] 00000022 com.ibm.ws.config.xml.internal.ConfigRefresher               A CWWKG0017I: The server configuration was successfully updated in 2.639 seconds.
[11/26/14 14:24:08:618 CST] 00000022 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      W CWWKZ0014W: The application MHE_original could not be started as it could not be found at location MHE.war.
[11/26/14 14:24:10:828 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      I CWWKZ0018I: Starting application MHE_original.
[11/26/14 14:24:13:298 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.webapp.WebGroup                 I SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: MHE.
[11/26/14 14:24:13:298 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer                                      I SRVE0250I: Web Module MHE has been bound to default_host.
[11/26/14 14:24:13:298 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl                     A CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:8080/MHE2/
[11/26/14 14:24:13:439 CST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.AppMessageHelper                      A CWWKZ0001I: Application MHE_original started in 2.486 seconds.
[11/26/14 14:25:22:460 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN8501I: The session manager did not find a persistent storage location; HttpSession objects will be stored in the local application server's memory.
[11/26/14 14:25:22:491 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0176I: A new session context will be created for application key default_host/MHE2
[11/26/14 14:25:22:538 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.util                                              I SESN0172I: The session manager is using the Java default SecureRandom implementation for session ID generation.
[11/26/14 14:25:33:994 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               I SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [MHE]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[11/26/14 14:25:34:619 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               I SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [MHE]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[11/26/14 14:25:34:619 CST] 0000002b org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[11/26/14 14:25:34:947 CST] 0000002b springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext I Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Nov 26 14:25:34 CST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[11/26/14 14:25:35:072 CST] 0000002b rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader I Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[11/26/14 14:25:35:919 CST] 0000002b g.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean I Loading properties file from class path resource [restServices.properties]
[11/26/14 14:25:36:122 CST] 0000002b org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1503 ms
[11/26/14 14:25:36:169 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               I SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [MHE]:.Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher'
[11/26/14 14:25:36:169 CST] 0000002b org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet            I FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization started
[11/26/14 14:25:36:169 CST] 0000002b springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext I Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 26 14:25:36 CST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[11/26/14 14:25:36:169 CST] 0000002b rg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader I Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]
[11/26/14 14:25:37:060 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://96.fwk1553324600/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [bundleresource://96.fwk1553324600/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://96.fwk1553324600/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:419)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.setValue(ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:387)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:460)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1063)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6092)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:203)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:448)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:253)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:559)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:991)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

[11/26/14 14:25:37:078 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundleresource://95.fwk1553324600/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [bundleresource://95.fwk1553324600/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundleresource://95.fwk1553324600/
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:52)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:212)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:598)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(ServletContextResourcePatternResolver.java:92)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:419)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.setValue(ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.java:159)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:387)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:460)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:150)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:325)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:1095)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:1063)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:6092)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.startWebApp(DynamicVirtualHost.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost.createRunnableHandler(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.internal.VirtualHostImpl.discriminate(VirtualHostImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:203)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:448)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:253)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:174)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:559)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:991)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

[11/26/14 14:25:37:085 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\db2java.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:086 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jeapCore-03.02.1.2.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\upload.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.1.1\httpclient-4.1.1.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.1\httpcore-4.1.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.4\commons-codec-1.4.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.12\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.12\jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:102 CST] 0000002b ramework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver W Skipping [C:\Users\e049447\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.1.2.RELEASE\spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar] because it does not denote a directory
[11/26/14 14:25:37:118 CST] 0000002b framework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer I Loading properties file from file [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\environment.properties]
[11/26/14 14:25:37:118 CST] 0000002b framework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer I Loading properties file from file [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\extended.properties]
[11/26/14 14:25:37:118 CST] 0000002b framework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer I Loading properties file from file [C:\STS\ws\MHE_original\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\restServices.properties]
[11/26/14 14:26:57:225 CST] 0000002b SystemOut                                                    O pchttp://localhost:8080/MHE2/log/display/last
[11/26/14 14:26:57:475 CST] 0000002b b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping I Mapped "{[/log/display/last],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> com.ma.mhe.common.controller.Lo_Controller.getFirst(com.ma.mhe.log.domain.Mas60010)
[11/26/14 14:26:58:209 CST] 0000002b b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter I Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 26 14:25:36 CST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[11/26/14 14:26:58:459 CST] 0000002b b.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter I Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 26 14:25:36 CST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
[11/26/14 14:26:58:616 CST] 0000002b .springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping I Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
[11/26/14 14:26:58:678 CST] 0000002b org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet            I FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 82509 ms
[11/26/14 14:26:58:678 CST] 0000002b com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [MHE_original] [/MHE2] [mvc-dispatcher]: Initialization successful.
[11/26/14 14:27:07:544 CST] 0000001a com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet
```

Comment: Hi. I am very interested to receive some suggestions for this thread. If someone need extra info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue today, 
it looks like the problem is, that the ClassLoader.getResources() returns URLs with protocol "file" and not "jar" and in certain cases does not return the jar files in shared libraries as separate resource URLs but the shared library location (e.g. the folder containing the JARs) as a single resource URL. This seems to confuse the `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` somewhere down the road.

I solved it by

1. overwriting the `convertClassLoaderURL` method and explicitly instantiate a JAR resource if the URL protocol is "file" and the extension is ".jar", and
2. overwriting the `doFindPathMatchingFileResources` method to search inside JAR files of resources that represent directories.

```java
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext() {

    protected ResourcePatternResolver getResourcePatternResolver() {
        return new ServletContextResourcePatternResolver(this) {

            protected Resource convertClassLoaderURL(URL url) {
                if (url.getProtocol().equals("file") && url.getFile().endsWith(".jar")) {
                    try {
                        return new UrlResource("jar", url + "!/");
                    } catch (final MalformedURLException ex) {
                        //LOG.catching(ex);
                    }
                }
                return new UrlResource(url);
            }

            protected Set<Resource> doFindPathMatchingFileResources(Resource rootDirResource, String subPattern) throws IOException {
                Set<Resource> matches = super.doFindPathMatchingFileResources(rootDirResource, subPattern);
                try {
                    File rootDir = rootDirResource.getFile();
                    if (rootDir.isDirectory()) {
                        Set<Resource> containedJARs = doFindMatchingFileSystemResources(rootDir, "*.jar");
                        for (Resource jar : containedJARs) {
                            Set<Resource> matchingResourcesFoundInJar = doFindPathMatchingJarResources(convertClassLoaderURL(jar.getURL()), subPattern);
                            matches.addAll(matchingResourcesFoundInJar);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (final IOException ex) {
                    // LOG.catching(ex);
                }
                return matches;
            }

        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet a similar problem when migrating app from tomcat to Liberty, finally I find a way to solve it by debugging spring code, below is my fix, FYI:

origin code:

```
        //old process (tomcat)
        dispatcherServletConfiguration = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
```

change it to:

```
    //changes for Liberty
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServletConfiguration = null;
    String serverType = System.getProperty("server.type");
    if(serverType != null && serverType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("liberty")) {
        dispatcherServletConfiguration = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(){
            protected ResourcePatternResolver getResourcePatternResolver() {
                PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(this) {
                    protected Resource convertClassLoaderURL(URL url) {
                        if(url.getProtocol().equals("file") && url.getFile().endsWith(".jar")) {
                            try {
                                return new UrlResource("jar", url + "!/");
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                //log and swallow it.
                                log.warn("Error when convert UrlResource from 'file' to 'jar'.", ex);
                            }
                        }
                        //old process
                        return new UrlResource(url);
                    }
                }; 
                return resolver;
            }
        };
    } else {
        //old process (tomcat)
        dispatcherServletConfiguration = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We saw this issue when our project was using version 4.3.4.RELEASE of spring.
Updating to the latest (4.3.22.RELEASE at the time) made the issue go away.